# nant script to execute sqlplus , does not return error code

Tags: sqlplus, nant

My nant script to execute sqlplus.exe looks like following

exec program="sqlplus.bat"
            basedir="${base.dir}"
            workingdir="${base.dir}" output="log.txt" failonerror="false" resultproperty="execresult"

arg line="${app.sqlplus} ${db.username} ${db.password} ${db.schema} ${var.exec.file} ${db.username} ${db.password}"

end exec

SqlPlus.bat has following contents

echo exit | %1 %2/%3@%4 @%5 %6 %7

I would ideally want to check the "execresult" which is the error code from exec command and show the respective message.

I have tried using the following statement in my SQL file but it did not help.

WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE

Could you please point out the problem and possible solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest answer is to remove the `output` and `failonerror` on your `exec` task because then NAnt will naturally show the message as it fails the build.  I'm guessing you've avoided that because you want to handle some non-zero exit codes as warnings or success because you want to handle some non-zero exit codes as warnings or success.  In that case:

```
<loadfile file="log.txt" property="execoutput" />
<fail if="${int::parse(execresult)>8" message="${execoutput}" />
```

Comment: Hi robrich, Thank you for spending time on this. I am seeing this response today after 2 yrs of posting this. I cannot verify this as I have moved on and dont use Nant anymore. I hope this would work however.